# Transitioning between menu screens with QStateMachine

Tags: c++, qt, transition, qwidget, qstatemachine

I am considering transitioning between menu screens in a game by using `QStateMachine`. However, I'm unsure how to kick off some code (e.g. `show()` a `QWidget`) upon a transition between states occurring. I can do it quite easily with plain old signals (see commented out code), but I figure that I could probably do some fancy animation upon switching screens using transitions.

Here's my code:

Edit: updated as per Koying's suggestion.

**ApplicationWindow.h**:

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <QStateMachine>

#include "MainMenu.h"
#include "LoadGameMenu.h"

class ApplicationWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ApplicationWindow();
private slots:
    void mainMenuButtonClicked();
    void loadGameMenuButtonClicked();
private:
    MainMenu* mainMenu;
    LoadGameMenu* loadGameMenu;

    QStateMachine stateMachine;

    QStackedWidget* stack;
};
```

**ApplicationWindow.cpp**:

```
ApplicationWindow::ApplicationWindow()
{
    resize(800, 600);

    stack = new QStackedWidget(this);

    mainMenu = new MainMenu();
    setCentralWidget(mainMenu);
    loadGameMenu = new LoadGameMenu();

    QState* mainMenuState = new QState();
    QState* loadGameMenuState = new QState();

    QAbstractTransition* loadTransition = mainMenuState->addTransition(
        mainMenu, SIGNAL(loadGameClicked()), loadGameMenuState);
    connect(loadTransition, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(loadGameMenuButtonClicked()));

    QAbstractTransition* mainMenuTransition = loadGameMenuState->addTransition(
        loadGameMenu, SIGNAL(backToMainMenuClicked()), mainMenuState);
    connect(mainMenuTransition, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(mainMenuButtonClicked()));

    stateMachine.addState(mainMenuState);
    stateMachine.addState(loadGameMenuState);

    stateMachine.setInitialState(mainMenuState);
    stateMachine.start();
}

void ApplicationWindow::mainMenuButtonClicked()
{
    setCentralWidget(mainMenu);
}

void ApplicationWindow::loadGameMenuButtonClicked()
{
    setCentralWidget(loadGameMenu);
}
```

**LoadGameMenu.h:**

```
#include <QtGui>

class LoadGameMenu : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    LoadGameMenu();
signals:
    void backToMainMenuClicked();
private:
    QPushButton* loadGameButton;
    QPushButton* backToMainMenuButton;
};
```

**LoadGameMenu.cpp:**

```
#include "LoadGameMenu.h"

LoadGameMenu::LoadGameMenu()
{
    loadGameButton = new QPushButton(tr("Load"));
    backToMainMenuButton = new QPushButton(tr("Main Menu"));

    QObject::connect(backToMainMenuButton, SIGNAL(clicked()),
        this, SIGNAL(backToMainMenuClicked()));

    QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout();
    layout->addWidget(loadGameButton);
    layout->addWidget(backToMainMenuButton);
    layout->setContentsMargins(300, 400, 300, 200);
    setLayout(layout);
}
```

**MainMenu.h:**

```
#include <QtGui>

class MainMenu : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MainMenu();
signals:
    void newGameClicked();
    void loadGameClicked();
private slots:
    void exit();
private:
    QPushButton* newGameButton;
    QPushButton* loadGameButton;
    QPushButton* exitGameButton;

    QMenu* fileMenu;
};
```

**MainMenu.cpp:**

```
#include "MainMenu.h"

MainMenu::MainMenu()
{
    newGameButton = new QPushButton(tr("New Game"), this);
    loadGameButton = new QPushButton(tr("Load Game"));
    exitGameButton = new QPushButton(tr("Exit"));

    QObject::connect(newGameButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SIGNAL(newGameClicked()));
    QObject::connect(loadGameButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SIGNAL(loadGameClicked()));
    QObject::connect(exitGameButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), qApp, SLOT(quit()));

    QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout();
    layout->addWidget(newGameButton);
    layout->addWidget(loadGameButton);
    layout->addWidget(exitGameButton);
    layout->setContentsMargins(300, 200, 300, 200);
    setLayout(layout);
}

void MainMenu::exit()
{
    if( QMessageBox::question(
        this,
        tr("Exit?"),
        tr("Do you really want to exit the game?"),
        QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No,
        QMessageBox::No
        ) == QMessageBox::Yes
    )
    {
        qApp->quit();
    }
}
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <QtGui>

#include "ApplicationWindow.h"

int main(int argv, char **args)
{
    QApplication app(argv, args);

    ApplicationWindow window;
    window.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

So, how do I trigger some behaviour or action when a transition occurs?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To actually do something on a state transition, you have to connect to the `triggered()` signal of the transition, e.g.

```
QAbstractTransition* trMainLoad = mainMenuState->addTransition(mainMenu, SIGNAL(loadGameClicked()), loadGameMenuState);
connect(trMainLoad , SIGNAL(triggered()), SLOT(...));
```

Comment: Cheers. I've done that, but now I'm getting: `Unhandled exception at 0x779815de (ntdll.dll) in Hello Notepad.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xabababaf.` The exception happens inside `mainMenuButtonClicked()` - am I not supposed to call `setCentralWidget` twice? I've updated my original post with my new code.

Comment: According to `setCentralWidget()` doc: `QMainWindow takes ownership of the widget pointer and deletes it at the appropriate time.`, so your mainMenu is probably destroyed when you do the `setCentralWidget(loadGameMenu);`

Comment: Wouldn't appropriate time mean when there are no references to the pointer left? How else can I show different `Widget`s (screens) inside a `QMainWindow`? I'm only doing it this way due to inexperience - I'm open to other options.

Comment: This is plain c++, there is no reference counting by default. For a simple first approach, I'd suggest to instantiate your widgets into the `ApplicationWindow::...clicked()` slots and call `mainMenuButtonClicked()` in your c'tor

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - why call `mainMenuButtonClicked()` in the constructor? And why create my widgets in the `mainMenuButtonClicked()` and `loadGameMenuButtonClicked()` methods?

Comment: As said above, because the previous widget will be deleted when you assign a new one via `setCentralWidget`, so one of the possible solution is to recreate them every time. Another is to make them child of the static, existing centralWidget() and show()/hide() them appropriately.

Comment: @Mitch Another alternative is to make them pages of a QStackedWidget; combine this with a QSignalMapper (to map buttons to widgets) and you can make a very nice menu system pretty easily.

Comment: Thanks @tmpearce, that worked perfectly. Final code for anyone that's interested: http://pastebin.com/YhbHHJNe