# How to connect the same Widget to multiple QSignalMapper mappings

Tags: c++, qt, menu, mapping, signals-slots

Following on from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9651976/transitioning-between-menu-screens-with-qstatemachine/), I have a menu system as follows:

```
MainMenu > (Load Game button clicked) > LoadGameMenu
LoadGameMenu > (Back To Main Menu button clicked) > MainMenu
LoadGameMenu > (Load button clicked) > GameScreen
```

However, when I click on the Load button, the MainMenu is shown instead. Here's my code:

```
ApplicationWindow::ApplicationWindow()
{
    resize(800, 600);

    stack = new QStackedWidget(this);
    signalMapper = new QSignalMapper(this);

    mainMenu = new MainMenu(this);
    loadGameMenu = new LoadGameMenu(this);
    gameScreen = new GameScreen(this);

    stack->addWidget(mainMenu);
    stack->addWidget(loadGameMenu);
    stack->addWidget(gameScreen);

    connect(mainMenu, SIGNAL(loadGameClicked()), signalMapper, SLOT(map()));
    connect(loadGameMenu, SIGNAL(backToMainMenuClicked()), signalMapper, SLOT(map()));
    connect(loadGameMenu, SIGNAL(loadClicked()), signalMapper, SLOT(map()));

    signalMapper->setMapping(loadGameMenu, 0);
    signalMapper->setMapping(mainMenu, 1);
    signalMapper->setMapping(gameScreen, 2);

    connect(signalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(int)), stack, SLOT(setCurrentIndex(int)));

    setCentralWidget(stack);
}
```

I know I'm doing something wrong with the signal mapping, but I don't know what it is.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) `QSignalMapper` maps a `QObject* sender` to a (int, string, QWidget* or QObject*).  Since your "load" and "return to main menu" signals are being *sent from the same sender object* they will be mapped the same way.  The solution is to connect the `clicked` signal of the different buttons to the mapper directly (rather than through your `LoadGameMenu` object), so the *sender* is different.

2) Since you're using a `QStackedWidget`, I would strongly consider using the `QWidget*` mapping of `QSignalMapper`, and connect to `QStackedWidget::setCurrentWidget`.  This will be easier to maintain if/when you add more menu screens, rather than trying to keep up with which `int` index is which widget.  It also makes things more readable in your code, in my opinion.

Edit:  Looks like you're not understanding the `setMapping` function.  I'd take a look at the docs for better a better idea.  What you're doing there is mapping the first argument (the sender) to a signal to be sent (the second argument).  In your original code, you're mapping `LoadGameMenu` to `0`.  Any time a signal is sent to the mapper from `LoadGameMenu`, `0` is sent to stackedWidget::setCurrentIndex` - which is why both buttons are returning you to the same place.

Comment: Thanks @tmpearce. I'm not sure I like having to expose `LoadGameMenu`'s buttons though... is there a nicer way to do it? New code (haven't connected all buttons directly yet): http://pastebin.com/tjtVuqm3

Comment: @Mitch You have multiple options... 1) Pass the signal mapper (and perhaps the int/QWidget* to which buttons are supposed to be mapped) to your LoadGameMenu; this exposes the signal mapper to that class, so you'd have to decide if it is better or not, perhaps a bit better encapsulated than you've got now. 2) Let the menu class do `connect` (as in 1), and return `QObject*` rather than `QPushButton*` to the caller for mapping purposes; 3) Create a helper class to relay your button-click signals, and create an object of that class for each button you need to map - protects the button itself.

Answer (score 1):

`QSignalMapper` relies on the sender of the signal to do the mapping, and you are connecting `loadGameMenu` twice.

If the sender is `loadGameMenu`, it will always show index 0.

It'd be probably best to connect directly to the buttons inside your `loadGameMenu` widget.